# Changing copy Entire Row to Copy Range based on Quantity

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that goes through a range and copies the row into a second sheet based on a "quantity". I can only make this work if I copy the entire row, I can't get it to work with just a range.

```
Public Sub CopyData()

' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
Dim rngSinglecell As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
Dim intCount As Integer

' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
Set rngQuantityCells = Range("P29", Range("P29").End(xlDown))

For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells
    ' Check if this cell actually contains a number
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) Then
        ' Check if the number is greater than 0
        If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
            ' Copy this row as many times as .value
            For intCount = 1 To rngSinglecell.Value
                ' Copy the row into the next emtpy row in Generate Control Sheet Import
                Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Generate Control Sheet Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                ' The above line finds the next empty row.

            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Instead of copying the entire Row I need it to copy a A29:G29 rngQuantityCells times (P29), then move onto the next row (A30:G30) and copy that into the next black row rngQuantityCells number of times (P30)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you are looking for the following:

```
Range("A:G").Rows(rngSinglecell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Generate Control Sheet Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

you can also avoid looping for the copy part:

```
        If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then Range("A:G").Rows(rngSinglecell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Generate Control Sheet Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell.Value)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the resize function would work? 
For example: 
if rngSingleCell is P29, then resize(,7) would select P29:V29. 
I need it to select A29:G29.

Althought thinking about it maybe an offset+resize might work....

Comment: I sse now what you actually meant. See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution, granted being rather convoluted! I have changed the final line to:

```
                Range("A" & rngSinglecell.Row, "G" & rngSinglecell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Generate Control Sheet Import").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                ' The above line finds the next empty row.
```

There will clearly be a better solution from someone